# role is not attaching to user in custom laravel registration function in many-to-many relathinship

Tags: php, laravel

Here is a custom laravel registration code snippet I created for users to registration into my application.

```
public function registration(Request $request)
{
    // validators

    $user = $this->create($request->all());

    $this->guard()->login($user);
    return response()->json(['status' => true, 'msg' => "Successfully registered"], 200);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name'  => $data['last_name'],
        'email'      => $data['email'],
        'password'   => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $user->roles()->attach(\App\Role::where('name', 'Subscriber')->first());
    return $user;
}

protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard();
}
```

Everything is still working great except it is not attaching roles to the user. I tried `tinker` to create a user and `attach` role for the user. It's also working in `tinker`.

> `Role` model has a many-to-many relationship with `User` model.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `id` of the models while attaching the relationship models, you can do something like:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name'  => $data['last_name'],
        'email'      => $data['email'],
        'password'   => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $role = \App\Role::where('name', 'Subscriber')->first();
    $user->roles()->attach($role->id);
    return $user;
}
```

For reference see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)